# Find the number of employees who meet the requirements

Tags: sql

There is a query question assumes a company wants to hire new employees. The company's salary budget is 80,000, the recruitment requirements are:

1. Hire as many senior employees as possible.
2. After hiring the most senior employees, use the remaining budget to hire as many junior employees as possible.

Here are two sample tables:

| employee_id | experience | salary |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Junior | 15000 |
| 2 | Junior | 15000 |
| 3 | Junior | 25000 |
| 4 | Senior | 45000 |
| 5 | Senior | 60000 |
| 6 | Senior | 60000 |

| employee_id | experience | salary |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Junior | 30000 |
| 2 | Junior | 30000 |
| 3 | Junior | 45000 |
| 4 | Senior | 85000 |
| 5 | Senior | 90000 |
| 6 | Senior | 90000 |

For the first example, the desired outcome is to recruit `one senior` employee and `two junior` employees. For the second example, outcome is `zero senior` and `two junior`.

I try my plan in my PieCloudDB Database, but for the first example I can get the correct result, for the second example I get the following result:

| experience | accepted_candidates |
| --- | --- |
| Senior | 0 |
| Junior | 0 |

I don't know what's wrong, can anyone help me? By the way, is there anything that can be optimized in my query method? Thanks.

```
with t1 as (
    select
    *,
    sum(salary) over(partition by experience order by salary) total
    from Candidates
),
t2 as (
    select 'Senior' experience, count(employee_id) accepted_candidates
    from t1
    where experience = 'Senior' and total <=80000
),
t3 as (
    select 'Junior' experience, count(employee_id) accepted_candidates
    from t1
    where experience = 'Junior' and total <=80000 - (
        select max(total)
        from t1
        where experience = 'Senior' and total <=80000
    )   
)
select * 
from t2
union 
select * 
from t3
```

Comment: A [mcve] is expected to include the _desired result_ as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the minimum salary required for senior employees exceeds your budget, it will get `NULL`. You need to use `COALESCE` to filter out, otherwise it will affect the results of your query for junior employees. The following query has been tested in PostgreSQL and the output is correct.(PieCloudDB is compatible with PostgreSQL, so the query should be useful)

```
with senior as (
    select * from (
        select *, sum(salary) over(order by salary) s from Candidates 
        where experience = 'Senior'
    ) t where s <= 80000
), junior as (
    select * from (
        select *, sum(salary) over(order by salary) s from Candidates
        where experience = 'Junior'
    ) t where s <= COALESCE(80000 - (select max(s) from Senior), 80000)
)
select 'Senior' experience, count(*) accepted_candidates from senior
union 
select 'Junior', count(*) from junior;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH RankedCandidates AS (
    SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY experience ORDER BY salary DESC) AS rank
    FROM Candidates
),
SeniorCandidates AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM RankedCandidates
    WHERE experience = 'Senior'
),
JuniorCandidates AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM RankedCandidates
    WHERE experience = 'Junior'
),
SelectedSenior AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM SeniorCandidates
    WHERE salary <= 80000
),
SelectedJunior AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM JuniorCandidates
    WHERE salary <= (SELECT 80000 - ISNULL(SUM(salary), 0) FROM SelectedSenior)
)
SELECT 'Senior' AS experience, COUNT(*) AS accepted_candidates
FROM SelectedSenior
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Junior' AS experience, COUNT(*) AS accepted_candidates
FROM SelectedJunior;
```